# Colors: CIE XYZ model - Chromaticity graph

Tags: colors

I want to draw a section graph for XYZ CIE color model, like this one:

[image]

Do you have any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very briefly...

You can plot the spectral line (the horseshoe) by plotting the xy (I have XY not xy) data for the standard observer. Then you can find the polygon you need to fill by applying a convex hull algorithm to the points. Make a list of xy values you want to paint within the polygon. Find the z value for a fixed luminance by `z = 1 - x - y`. Convert to RGB - you will need a function called something like XYZtoRGB (there is a python module, or use the transform on wikipedia). You may want to increase the luminance by multiplying all the numbers by a constant or something first. Set the pixels at the xy locations to the RGB values. Plot along with the convex hull and/or the spectral line you calculated.

I have the data for the standard 2deg (I think) observer (I can't find a link) - you will need to divide by X+Y+Z to convert from XYZ to xyz. Send me a message if you want me to send them to you, there is too much data to post here.

Comment: So let's focus on just drawing the horseshoe first. I have a couple of questions more: 1. by data for the standard observer you mean some kind of array with values? What kind of values are those, what do they represent? 2. xy defines a plane with both x and y ranging [0:1]? 3. How to compute RGB color for a given point on the xy plane? 4. Will I need to use convex hull algorithm to plot the spectral line? From your post it appears that this line is directly connected to the observer data you mentioned, is that right?

Comment: 1) I've uploaded the data here: it is wavelength, log X, log Y, log Z, http://www.sussex.ac.uk/Users/lw80/cones.csv These are known as the cone fundamentals and they represent the relative reponse of the different cones in ones retina to different monochromatic lights. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space#The_CIE_standard_observer 2. xy is a bit like the rg of rgb, but transformed, they are the letters used to represent the coordinates by colour people. 3. download a package. 4. No you wont, this is the xy data, but it is an effective way of getting the shape of the colored patch.

Comment: That was exactly 600 characters

Comment: The data lacks logz for wavelength 615+. Is that not a problem? 1. I suppose I will iterate over all xy points in the plane and color them accordingly - how do I use your data to determine the color?

Comment: Assume that `z = 0`, it's ommited because `log 0 = -infinity`. Iterate over all xy points in the horseshoe. The colour is just a transformation from xyz to rgb. http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_RGB_XYZ_Matrix.html

Comment: So using the data did give me a horseshoe line (YEY!) with proper colors, but its just a line atm. For the points on the line I had all information I needed -> X Y and Z chromatic coordinates for easy conversion. But for the points inside of the horseshoe -> I don't have Z. Which one should I use?

Comment: so, if you make sure you are using xy not XY, wehere `x = X/(X+Y+Z)`, `y=Y/(X+Y+Z)` then `z =1-x-y`. So use that. As I said earlier, you may want to change the brightness by multiplying all x,y and z by a constant.

Comment: Just for clarification - There is a way to convert "big" X Y Z to RGB using the link you provided. These X Y describe the axes of my bitmap (axis-x and axis-y). To calculate x and y from X and Y I would have to know Z, because Z is also on the right side of equations for x and y. How do I calculate it? Or do I have to change my axis-x and axis-y to represent small x and y, then convert data from the file to small xyz and plot it, then fill polygon? Because then I do not know a way to convert small xyz to RGB as it is not in the link you posted.

Comment: Obviously converting the data from file to xyz will give the same values as XYZ. But the question for converting small xyz to RGB is still unanswered for me. It appears incorrect to me to assume that inside the polygon for every point: X = x, Y = y, Z = z (these equations are correct for points on spectral line) which would allow me to use XYZ to RGB conversion. Am I wrong?

Comment: The space ignores brightness, which is "big" X+Y+Z, in fact, it assumes it is 1. So everywhere on the plane, in "little" xyz, `z = 1 - x - y`. If we take the coordinates `(x,y,1-x-y)` this is a colour in "big" XYZ with brightness = X+Y+Z = 1. To get a different brightness multiply by k to get `(kx, ky, k(1-x-y))`

Comment: So for brigthness = 1 it comes down to: foreach point (x,y) in plane if (x,y) is in polygon created by spectral line -> let X = x, Y = y, Z = 1-x-y -> for these XYZ find RGB -> draw this RGB? I'm sorry if these were dumb questions, I just wanted to reassure myself.

Comment: What would be the optimal range of value k for setting brightness?

Comment: Seems like k in [0;3] works OK for me. I read somewhere that X,Y,Z nominal values are in [0;1], so this could be the reason why.

Answer (score 0):

The `colour` Python module has a `plotting` submodule where this kind of plot is one of the provided plots. See documentation for [plot_chromaticity_diagram_CIE1931](https://colour.readthedocs.io/en/develop/generated/colour.plotting.plot_chromaticity_diagram_CIE1931.html) and [plot_sds_in_chromaticity_diagram_CIE1931](https://colour.readthedocs.io/en/develop/generated/colour.plotting.plot_sds_in_chromaticity_diagram_CIE1931.html#colour.plotting.plot_sds_in_chromaticity_diagram_CIE1931)

It uses Matplotlib under the hood.